# Submit values true if not checked and false if checked (from webform to salesforce)

Tags: drupal, webforms, salesforce

I have field with checkbox and it is need to be synced with salesforce field. What I want if I select checkbox the values should sent to salesforce false and if I unchecked field values should sent to true in salesforce.

Below is my code:

```
               function registerAtSalesforce($first_name,$communication){

try{



    $data = [
        'userInput' => [
            
            'FirstName' => $first_name,
            'MarketingCommunicationOptOut' => $communication ? false : true,
        ]
    ];
```

I have put condition in MarketingCommunicationOptOut which field in salesforce and I have put condition you can see according to my requirement( I want to send opposite values) but I have check in salesforce nothing is pushing to salesforce and If put condition like below

```
            'MarketingCommunicationOptOut' => $communication ? true: false,
```

It always push values to Salesforce (true) whether If I checked or unchecked my field in my Drupal field.

Comment: Where is ````$communication```` getting it's value set at?

Comment: Before that happens, I would also add a ````console.log($communication)```` so you can see exactly what the value is for each instance of checked and not checked.